# Change background color for text block

Tags: environments, backgrounds

I want to change the style for `\quote` areas in my entire document. These three lines is what I came up with. Font and margins changes take effect but not the bg color. Only the first char's bg color changes, not the the entire quote block.

```
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.85}

\newenvironment{myblock}
{\small \addtolength{\leftskip}{10mm} \addtolength{\rightskip}{10mm} \colorbox{block-gray} } 
{\normalsize \addtolength{\leftskip}{0mm} \addtolength{\rightskip}{0mm}}

\renewcommand{\quote}{\myblock}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For such jobs, `tcolorbox` is more suitable. The advantage here is the box is breakable across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}                    %% just for demo
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=block-gray,grow to right by=-10mm,grow to left by=-10mm,
boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,breakable}
\begin{document}
\noindent
  \begin{myquote}
    \lipsum
  \end{myquote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In your method, you may better use `environ` package. However, this is not breakable across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,showframe}
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.85}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myblock}
{\colorbox{block-gray}{%
\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
\small\addtolength{\leftskip}{10mm}
\addtolength{\rightskip}{10mm}
\BODY}}
}

\renewcommand{\quote}{\myblock}
\renewcommand{\endquote}{\endmyblock}

\begin{document}
\noindent
  \begin{quote}
    The quote come here The quote come here The quote come here The quote come here The quote come hereThe quote come here The quote come here The quote come here The quote come here
  \end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Harish, both your solutions are valid for my document. However, there is one problem: how to make the quote block flow into the next page. It appears both solutions are trying hard to keep the blocks on the same page and they are messing up vertical spacing in-between paragraphs surrounding the quote. I'm unsure if this calls for posting another question.

Comment: @EmacsUser In your approach using `\colorbox` (second one in the answer), breaking across pages is not possible. That is why I recommended `tcolorbox`. In my `tcolorbox` solution, just add `breakable` to the options like `...boxsep=0pt,breakable}`

Comment: Adding `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` does not work for me, I had to remove the `[most]` option, otherwise pdflatex always fails. Additionally I had to remove the `breakable` from the `newtcolorbox` definition.