# How can I make code blocks in LaTeX, like Markdown

Tags: csquotes

In Markdown, use a pair of ``` for code blocks,

[image: Markdown code blocks]

How can I achieve it in LaTeX?

I use the packet `csquotes` and encounter two questions:

- how to remove double quotes
- how to add background color

Comment: Strange: I know ``` to start and end a code block…

Comment: For those not intimately familiar with markdown, can you elaborate on how one should interpret single and double backticks, as compared with the triple-backtick?

Comment: Actually I believe [markdown itself](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) doesn't make any blocks with backticks but only `<code>`/`</code>` pairs. The triple-tic introducing a code block is part of the GitHub-flavored markdown. The triple-tic for a blockquote may be some other flavor?

Comment: `csquotes` has its own facilities to create block quotations if a quoted string is longer than a specified length, which you can adjust. Otherwise you can use  `quote` or `quotation` environment from standard LaTeX. Adding the colorbox would be an extra customization, though.

Comment: @spark, Did you find something easier? Even something for just one word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the color part of the problem, I used a `tcolorbox` approach as given in the answer to this question: [Change background color for text block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238294/change-background-color-for-text-block)

For the markdown parsing one can borrow and adapt from my answer at [Use Markdown-style formatting for bold and italic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236439/use-markdown-style-formatting-for-bold-and-italic/236457#236457).

Here I interpret triple backticks as delimiters for a `myquote` environment, using the macro `\triplequote`.  Not knowing from your question how to interpret single and double backticks, I merely show how they are parsed, using placeholders defined in the macros `\singlequote` and `\doublequote`.

The macros `\quoteON` and `\quoteOFF` are used to enable and disable the active parsing.

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=block-gray,grow to right by=-10mm,grow to left by=-10mm,
boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,breakable}
\makeatletter
\def\quoteparse{\@ifnextchar`{\quotex}{\singlequote}}
\def\quotex#1{\@ifnextchar`{\triplequote\@gobble}{\doublequote}}
\makeatother
\def\singlequote#1`{[StartQ]#1[EndQ]\quoteON}
\def\doublequote#1``{[StartQQ]#1[EndQQ]\quoteON}
\long\def\triplequote#1```{\begin{myquote}\parskip 1ex#1\end{myquote}\quoteON}
\def\quoteON{\catcode``=\active}
\def\quoteOFF{\catcode``=12}
\quoteON
\def`{\quoteOFF \quoteparse}
\quoteOFF
\begin{document}
\quoteON
This is a `test of single quoted` material 
and this is a ``test of double quoted material``, and this
is the test of a ```triple quoted material. We will make it long
enough to test line wrapping and we will even\\
add a manual linebreak.

Even a new paragraph.```  Resuming normal text.

\quoteOFF
Here should be triple backticks ```xxx```
\end{document}
````

[image]

Once it is known how single-quoted and double-quoted material should behave, those macros can be adjusted to implement it.