# Blockquotes in LateX

Tags: formatting

Is there a way to make pretty, colorful blockquotes in LateX

> like this?

This might be a duplicate of [How can I make blockquotes in LaTeX, like Markdown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265792/how-can-i-make-blockquotes-in-latex-like-markdown), but I don't like the ugly gray blockquote which that produces.

I know that answer lets you choose different colors other than gray, but is there a way to add fancy borders

> like this

or like on the other StackExchange websites (Math comes to mind for me).

Comment: Have you looked at what tcolorbox can do? (the solution used in that answer), if you can think of it, it is highly likely that it can be done with tcolorbox

Comment: I will do this -- thank you for help! and apologies for the dumb question.

Comment: However, in answer is proposed to use `tcolorbox`, where you can use any color you wish. This answers seems to solve your problem. See `tcolorbox` documentation, there is big number of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Here was my solution, modified slightly from the previous answer and the tcolorbox manual:

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}     
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=yellow!20!white,colframe=yellow!75!black,grow to right by=-10mm,grow to left by=-10mm,
    boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,breakable} \makeatletter

\newcommand{\blockquote}[1]{  \begin{myquote}  #1  \end{myquote}  }
```